# how to push a file first time but avoid from next time (from push, hence pull)

Tags: php, git, gitignore

I have a file named local.config.php,in my repo. I want this file to be fetched in git clone (ie first time pull only) and from next time , I don't want this file to be tracked. This file (after clone) should be treated as it is in `.gitignore`.
Whenever anyone changes local.config.php on his computer (after taking clone of my repo), the `git status` should not show this file there to stage or commit.

Comment: When you pushing your code to git repo then push the config file with common setting and later in second commit add .gitignore  file by adding the file name in it....It will allow user to get file while checkout but will not show in diff while pushing or pulling

Comment: You're doing this to set a default configuration. *Don't*. Provide the default configuration elsewhere, and allow the user to set the real (or override-default) configuration in a file that's not committed in the first place. In other words, commit `local.config.php.sample` or `local.config.default.php` which is overridden by `.gitignore`d `local.config.php`. (I'm not saying you *cannot* do what you want—you can't but you can get fairly close—but rather, just don't even try. It makes for a miserable experience.)

Answer (score 1):

You can either add file to `.git/info/exclude` or tell git not to track local changes:

`git update-index --skip-worktree local.config.php`

You can read more on `git update-index` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Comment: Adding the file to an ignore or exclude entry will not do much good once the file is in the index. The `--skip-worktree` method mostly works, but requires that everyone who clones the repository do this step themselves. It's a solution, but it's the wrong way to go.

Comment: Everyone who takes clone, will need to take above step. This is not the solution that i want.

Comment: Generally I agree that a *.default file under VCS and a user file in .gitignore is a better way to go here; although if you don't want to switch to this approach you can add some more automation to the process by putting a `post-checkout` hook into the repository and setting `core.hooksPath` to that directory.